# Very old off topic questions being closed

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, scope, old-questions

I can't seem to find the question on meta about it now, but I seem to recall there was a discussion sometime ago about closing questions that were asked a long time ago but would not be considered on topic today.

The guidance at that time was to leave them open (especially if they had a high view count).  I have noticed several questions recently that fit this description but have been closed anyway.  Have the rules changed or it it just like everything else on StackOverflow, they are not being adhered to?

Comment: No, the guidance would not have been to leave such posts open, off-topic now means such posts need to be closed to prevent broken windows leading to more broken windows. The guidance *may* have been to *not delete* such posts instead.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Several questions like this have been locked to prevent them being closed i.e. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/108699/good-php-orm-library

Comment: No, they are **not** locked to prevent closing. Locking prevents *voting*, as well as editing.

Comment: @MartijnPieters In particular the historical locks are mostly there to prevent *deletion*.  Posts that are very popular and very offtopic often end up being deleted, undeleted, closed, reopened, and constantly toggling between all of those states.  The lock is there to both prevent it from being open, but also prevent it from being deleted.

Comment: @Servy: well said, what I meant.

Answer (score -10, accepted):

**It is the deleting that is getting out of hand.**  Questions that were old with usefulness or popularity were not supposed to be deleted.  Closing them is fine, but they should really be locked.  Here's some good links about this:

[The Great Question Deletion Audit of 2010](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51097/the-great-question-deletion-audit-of-2010)

[Question deletions are getting out of hand](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50967/question-deletions-are-getting-out-of-hand)

[Community-led deletionism: a protocol for sanity](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124439/community-led-deletionism-a-protocol-for-sanity)

Here's some examples since I was asked.  I hope this doesn't start the usual comment arguments about how good or bad these questions are, the point is that many, many people thought they were useful, and they all had some level of popularity.  There are many more examples, but these are just a few closed as off-topic (or non-constructive) and deleted (10ks only).

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37359/what-c-sharp-mocking-framework-to-use

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/755465/do-you-say-no-to-c-sharp-regions

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/440269/whats-a-good-alternative-windows-console

Comment: I think perhaps these were the discussions I was recalling.  In my mind closed == deleted (even though I know there is a difference)

Comment: Could you provide some examples of this now? All you're linking to is old meta posts from years ago.

Comment: @hichris123, what do you mean?  Do you want new meta posts that say the same thing, or links to deleted off-topic questions.  If the latter then just look at the archive post of deleted questions.  If the former, then there are quite a few out there, but I don't think they reached the level of these, and there was certainly no post that showed that the SO perspective has changed.

Comment: I actually have a bunch of deleted posts that I haven't added to the archive yet, their deletion rate is getting overwhelming.

Comment: @LanceRoberts please do post some examples here

Comment: @JanDvorak, ok, there's 3 out of hundreds.  I'm not saying anything about whether these were bad or good, just that they were useful to many and popular, therefore helping people figure stuff out and helping the site to draw in new people.